# ASP.NET is not calling C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason this following ASP code is not calling the c# method "checkLastNames" that is suppose to be evaluated in the 'Visible=' field below.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnZ" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Z" 
            Height="20px" 
            Width="25px" 
            Font-Size="12px" 
            CommandArgument="Z" 
            OnClick="btnA_Click" 
            Visible='<%# checkLastNames("Z") %>' />
```

When I enter debug mode the method isn't even being called.  Visible just defaults to true. 
I've tried changing the method to return only false just to see if it would work but "Visible" is still defaulting to true.

```
protected bool checkLastNames(string s){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're using the `<%#` format.. it should be `<%= blah %>`. # is for databinding.

Comment: That's the databinding syntax...are you calling DataBind() in the codebehind?

Comment: No, it's not databound, so that part of the problem.  When I try with <%= %> I get an error : Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= checkLastNames("Z") %>' for the 'Visible' property.

Comment: Why not do this in the codebehind? It's much cleaner: `btnZ.Visible = checkLastNames("Z");`

Comment: Yes, you're right.  It is cleaner.  I'm doing that now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%#` is for databinding expressions, so this works only if the namingcontainer control of this Button  is databound.

For example in `Page_Load`:

```
this.DataBind();
```

But why not using codebehind in the first place?

```
btnZ.Visible = checkLastNames("Z");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm getting an error when I change the code (Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= checkLastNames("Z") %>' for the 'Visible' property.)  In any case, I'll just do it in code behind.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnZ" 
        runat="server" 
        Text="Z" 
        Height="20px" 
        Width="25px" 
        Font-Size="12px" 
        CommandArgument="Z" 
        OnClick="btnA_Click" 
        Visible='<%# checkLastNames("Z") %>' />
```

That # means it's only evaulated during a databind operation. So if you are not databinding the page explicitly (through calling DataBind()) then this won't show.

```
        Visible='<%= checkLastNames("Z") %>' />
```

You might want to try the code above. Also I would probably put this in a static function (assuming it's functionality is encapsulated in there)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnZ" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Z" 
            Height="20px" 
            Width="25px" 
            Font-Size="12px" 
            CommandArgument="Z" 
            OnClick="btnA_Click" 
            Visible='<%= checkLastNames("Z") %>' />
```